# Tool for checking JS doc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, gruntjs

Is there any tool or script that can check and compare your JS code with the generated documentation. Check if any parameters or return value types are specifed inncorrect?

I've generated my JS doc using grunt.

Comment: Ow, sorry, misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I use **Webstorm**, and that checks my method calls all the time with the JSDoc i have written for my method paramater.